# Cordova app cannot see web server

Tags: angularjs, cordova, google-chrome, webview, ionic-framework

- Ionic Framework version 1.4.0-alpha.5
- Cordova version 3.5.0-0.2.4
- Windows 7 64 bit
- Nexus 5 running Android 5

I have an Ionic Framework app that accesses a web API. This Web API is hosted at 192.168.0.10 (my development machine). For whatever reason I am getting nothing but 404 errors when trying to access this server via $http.

If I access 192.168.0.10 from my PC, it works as expected.
If I access 192.168.0.10 from chrome on my mobile phone, it works as expected
If I access 192.168.0.10 from the Ionic/Cordova app on my phone I see 404 errors via the web view inspector utility of the ADB chrome plugin.
When I change the remote web server address to the live URL ( e.g. https://my.server.com/ ) it works as expected.

I have added 192.168.0.10 to my access rights in config.xml

This used to be fine in the past, but not it doesn't work... and I am stumped! Anyone have any ideas?

[image: 404 Error for 192.168.0.10]

**UPDATE** I've tried accessing 192.168.0.10 from a brand new test app and it works as expected, I can only assume at this stage it's something to do with a plugin...

Comment: If your device is connected to the network, then it must be able to find the server. Could it be something related to CORS? You should try `$http.jsonp` in that case.

Comment: Thanks Keval, I've had specific CORS errors in the past, but in this instance it's a flat out 404. By my understanding, I cannot make POST requests via JSONP and this is required at this stage.

Comment: Ah, okay. And, just in-case, be sure that your app is having internet/network access. And you said it worked before and now it doesn't, so check everything that you've changed. Meanwhile, I will dig up a bit and try to know what could be wrong

Comment: Try adding this to your controller: `$http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';`

Also, could you try a simple $http.get and echo back something?

Comment: Hi Keval, same again when using GET and setting the default headers for post. However, I did try creating a new ionic app from scratch and accessing the same location and it worked without issue.... I can only assume it's a plugin I've installed, but none of them should be relevant.

Comment: Oh, I see. Glad to know you found the cause (or atleast, neared to the solution).